# How to show tracking in a user flow diagram?

Tags: diagram, dataflow-diagram, flow-diagram, dfd

I have made a **user flow diagram** but just wanted to ask you guys about clarification on displaying "tracking".

Let's say these are the requirements

1. User enters a web page to browse products
2. User selects product
3. **The selected product is tracked by Google analytics ( making a request to google servers)**
4. User goes to order page to purchase product or not

What would be the correct way of showing **step number 3 i**n my user flow diagram?

Please see screenshot below and let me know of any suggestions

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A data-flow diagram differs from ordinary flow-charts:  instead of arrows showing the control flow (sequence of actions and decisions), the arrow should correspond to data moving from one function to the other. On each arrow you should be able to write the data that is transmitted.

If a product is tracked with analytics, the arrow to `Google tracking` would probably be a product.  The question then is:

- does `Google tracking` return something to `selects product`? In this case an arrow in the opposite direction is missing (for the response).
- Or will another function get data from `Google tracking` to exploit the tracking? This function would be missing.
- or is `Google tracking` considered to be some data store that would be read elsewhere.

### Unrelated to your question

Does the `selects product` get the product selected from the web page ?  Or is this something that receives data from the user?  Or is it in fact a part of your webpage?

On the symbols,  the main DFD notations use circles instead of boxes, or rounded rectangles.  The diamond and the circle here look like flow-chart diagram symbols and are confusing.